# Nobody can't view my github profile, repositories while I can still login normally

Tags: github

Just as the title, my account still able to login and to commit code normally but github doesn't track on those commit. No one can view my profile while I still can see it when I login. Here the link https://github.com/HMT2002 [image: Picture prove my account still here] Picture prove my account still here. I keep the private options as uncheck but it doesn't seem to do anything.[image: Setting's picture] I also try to push some code but github only keep track of other commit, not mine.[image: Github commit track][image: Mine commit]
And yes, I made a discussion on github community already, but look at the situation that no one can view my profile, I don't know whether I can't get the support or not, so I ask here to see anyone have similar experience share with me, please help.

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @avoshmo yes, I wrote a ticket everyday and took them couple day to contact back to me. Some of my repo hosting built .exe and .dll file. The system auto scan and report as threats, I have to remove them and they unbanned me. I don't know should I close this question or not.